# C - assigning a true int value to void pointer instead of address/pointer value?

Tags: c

I'm having to deal with a generalised linked list so I cannot just turn the data format from a `void *` to an `int`.

Miniscule version:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *data;
    int i = 100;
    *((int*)data) = i;
    printf("%d", (int)data);
    return 0;
}
```

Keeps printing an address. Likewise, `data = &i` also returns an address. `data = i` just results in an error. I've tried all that I can and just cannot insert the value `i` into `data`.

Comment: You cannot dereference 'data' - it is uninitialized.  Nasal demons may ensue...

Comment: An excellent example of why GCC's / Clang's `-Wall` option is useful: they will heartily slap you for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `data` point to a valid memory address first:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *data = malloc(sizeof (int));
    int i = 100;
    *((int*)data) = i;
    printf("%d", *((int*)data));
    return 0;
}
```

Without that `malloc()`, double undefined behaviour(accessing an uninitialised object && writing data to a random address) will be invoked.

Also, change `(int)data` to `*((int*)data)` in your `printf()` statement. If `sizeof (int) > sizeof (void *)`, `data` will be truncated when being cast.

Comment: I still get an address returned instead of the desired `100` doing that :/

Comment: @Synlar Try `printf("%d", *((int*)data));`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a `void *` as a generalised container.

Got two options for integer or other data types

```
 void * data = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE)); // Datatype can be int in this case
```

Then

```
 *((int *)data) = SOME VALUE;
```

Then free it at some point

Otherwise one can usually assume an internet "fits" into a void *.

I would not go down this avenue.